# Number of ordered pairs of $(a,b)$ for which $ab = 90$, and $(a,b) \in \mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

So $90 = 2 \times 3^2 \times 5$ 
Suppose $a \gt b$
Then pairs of $(a,b) \in \{(90,1), (45,2),(30,3),(18,5),(15,6),(10,9)\}$
So will the number of *ordered* pairs be $6$ or $12$? Initially I thought it'd be $12$, but then came across a solution for some problem which confused me.

Comment: If you're talking about ordered pairs, the answer is $12$.  You have only listed half of the ordered pairs in your question because an ordered pair does not require that $a \gt b$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring I'll edit it. To clarify though, I took $a > b$ to work through the cases, though apparently you can just find the number of factors and that will be equal to the number of ordered pairs? I did see that in a comment somewhere. Any explanation from the original commenter?

Comment: As mentioned also by Robert , "ordered pairs" means that , for example , $(90/1)$ is distinct from $(1/90)$. In this case , the number of pairs is just the number of the divisors , here $12$. "$a>b$" gives here half of this number since the given number is not a perfect square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $ab=90$ and $a,b\in\Bbb{N}$. $a$ and $b$ are both factors of $90$. This means that under no other conditions the number of pairs $(a,b)$ is equal to the number of factors of $90$. We can create the pairs by letting $a$ be each of the factors of $90$ then let $b$ be $\frac{90}{a}$. In this case it is 12 pairs: $(1,90),(2,45),(3,30),(5,18),(6,15),(9,10),(10,9),(15,6),(18,5),(30,3),(45,2),(90,1)$

If we then add the additional condition that $a\gt b$ this will cut the number of pairs in half. For the two pairs $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ only one of the pairs will the left number be greater than the right number.

$$(1,90) \leftrightarrow (90,1)$$
$$(2,45) \leftrightarrow (45,2)$$
$$(3,30) \leftrightarrow (30,3)$$
$$(5,18) \leftrightarrow (18,5)$$
$$(6,15) \leftrightarrow (15,6)$$
$$(9,10) \leftrightarrow (10,9)$$

notice that all of the pairs on the right side are the pairs where $a>b$.

In the general case of the problem where $a,b\in\Bbb{N}\quad$ $ab=k$ and $a\ge b$. $k$ can be a square which means there will be one pair where $a=b$. This means switching the two values will not change the pair. This implies that the formula for the number of pairs is $\left\lceil\frac{f(k)}{2}\right\rceil$. Where $f(k)$ is the number of factors of $k$.